# express password validation throws an unwanted error cannot set headers after they are sent to client

Tags: node.js, express

what am i doing wrong

error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

```
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    !user && res.status(404).json("user not found");

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
      req.body.password,
      user.password
    );
    !validPassword && res.status(400).json("wrong password");
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

i have a try & catch block but still its throwing an error

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is you are responding to the client more than once. This is happening because you have `!user && res.status(404).json("user not found");` followed by `!validPassword && res.status(400).json("wrong password");`. What you should be doing is ending the function call after a response. This would look something like

```
if(!user) return res.status(404).json("user not found");
// Code

if(!validPassword) return res.status(400).json("wrong password");

// Code for valid information
```